# Syntax for conditions in aws_iam_policy resources in terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam

I am currently trying to implement an aws_iam_policy in terraform that looks like:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "policyName" {
  name        = "policyName"
  path        = "/"
 
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow"
        NotAction = [
          "iam:*"
        ]
        Resource = "*"
 
        Condition = {
          test = "StringEquals"
          variable = "s3:prefix"
          values = [
            "home/"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

However, when I try to deploy this in an environment I'm using within a team, I get an error saying there are syntax errors with this (the logs only point out the starting line and nowhere else). When I take out the Condition block the error disappears, so I know it's something to do with the condition. I have checked the terraform documentation and they do not have an `=` after the condition, but when I remove the `=` I get an error saying the `=` is expected. Would anyone know of the correct syntax/the right place to look for documentation regarding this (as stated previously the documentation at https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document doesn't work for me)?

Comment: Not exactly sure why the documentation is not working for you, but I provided an example using your question as a source to demonstrate syntactically correct use of the IAM policy data source. Let me know if you have further issues with getting your policy to validate, I'll try to be helpful if I can.

Comment: It would help to edit your question to include the exact error message(s) Terraform returned, so that it's possible to see what exactly Terraform reported and where.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would try an [`aws_iam_policy_document`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document) data block, like the following example:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "example" {

  statement {

    not_actions = [
      "iam:*",
    ]

    effect = "Allow"

    resources = [
      "*",
    ]

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "s3:prefix"
      values = [
        "home/"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And then add a `aws_iam_policy` resource that references this data source:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "policyName" {
  name   = "policyName"
  path   = "/"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.example.json
}
```

In my experience, this pattern has yielded the best validation when provisioning IAM policies.

Answer (score 11):

As an alternative to Joel Van Hollebeke's answer, a simple change to the Condition block in the original document would also work.

**Instead of :**

```
    Condition = {
      test = "StringEquals"
      variable = "s3:prefix"
      values = [
        "home/"
      ]
    }
```

**Use this:**

```
   Condition = {
      "StringEquals" = {
        "s3:prefix" = "home/"
      }
    }
```

Having said this, "aws_iam_policy_document" is still the most recommended way of doing this in terraform.

Answer (score 0):

Extending Saurabh Saxena's answer, you can also use variables in the condition block

```
variable "s3_location" {
  default = "home"
  description = "S3 bucket prefix location"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "policyName" {
  name        = "policyName"
  path        = "/"
 
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow"
        NotAction = [
          "iam:*"
        ]
        Resource = "*"
 
        Condition = {
          "StringEquals" = {
            "s3:prefix" = "${var.s3_location}/"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}
```